# Using the L.CRS.Simple in Leaflet, can I make my map wrap?

Tags: leaflet

I'm using [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html) with `L.CRS.Simple` and a `L.imageOverlay` custom non-earth map (no tiles). I'd love to wrap longitude around the image's bounds, but that doesn't seem to be supported in this CRS, or is it?

Any other solution I could use to make something like this happen?

```
const width = 10000;
const height = 7332;
var imageBounds = [[0, 0], [height, width]];

var map = L.map('map', {
    crs: L.CRS.Simple,
    minZoom: -2,
    maxZoom: 1,
    maxBounds: L.latLngBounds(
        L.latLng(0, 0), 
        L.latLng(height, width)
    )
});
map.fitBounds(imageBounds);

var mapLayer = L.imageOverlay('map.svg', imageBounds, {
    zIndex: 1,
    pane: 'mapPane',
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: It's possible to make it wrap, but not for `L.imageOverlay`, only for tile layers.